# Document license that explicitly forbids attribution of derived work

Tags: licensing

First of all: I hope this fits on this stackexchange. Sorry if it doesn't...

The title says it all. I want to write a document and I would like to put an open license on it (i.e. do whatever you want). However I am by no means willing to take any responsibility for derived work and would like the license to reflect that by requiring that any derived work not be attributed to me. So essentially I want a license that says:

"Do whatever you want with this text. Distribute it as you like. The only requirement I have is that you remove my name from any derived work".

Is that actually possible at all? Or should I then essentially pick a license that forbids derived work altogether?

Comment: You may want to look into [creative commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/).

Comment: Your goal is not entirely clear: do you want to completely disavow any connection to the original work that you create, or do you want to allow (or require) attribution for copies of the unaltered original – is the "don't blame me" thing specifically limited to derived works?

Comment: That's actually a good question. 
The thing is: I wouldn't mind people coming to me with questions regarding the original document so I wouldn't mind putting my name as author. So in that sense being attributed as author is only a practical thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy.

Don't put your name on it in the first place and state "The copyright owner grants a perpetual, non-exclusive, royalty-free licence to anyone provided that it is not attributed to the author."